# Solving a floored recurrence relation $F_n = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-1}}{d} \right\rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I initially wanted to solve the following recurrence relation:
$$F_n = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-1}}{d} \right\rfloor \text{ for } F_0, c, d \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}$$

Out of interest, I've also approached the problem more generally:

\begin{align*}
F_n &= a \cdot \lfloor b \cdot F_{n-1} \rfloor + c \tag{2}
\\
C_n &= a \cdot \lceil b \cdot C_{n-1} \rceil + c, \text{ for } a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}^+
\end{align*}

I wish to solve these generally.

##### Special case for (1) where $d|c$ and $c|d$

A special case for (1) where $c | d$ and $d|c$ can be found relatively easily.

> If $d | c$, then:
> $$F_n = c \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{c-1} \left\lfloor \frac{F_0}{d} \right\rfloor$$
> If $c|d$, then:
> $$F_n = c \left\lfloor \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{n-1} \frac{F_0}{d} \right\rfloor$$

The first is proven by using $d | c \implies \frac{c}{d} \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{Z} \left(\lfloor nm \rfloor = nm\right)$ on:

$$F_n = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{c}{d} \cdot  \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-2}}{d} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor = c \cdot \frac{c}{d} \cdot  \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-2}}{d} \right\rfloor $$

The second is proven using $c|d \implies \exists n \in \mathbb{Z} \left(\frac{d}{c} = \frac{1}{n}\right)$ and the property $\left\lfloor \frac{\lfloor x / m \rfloor}{n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{mn} \right\rfloor$:

$$F_n = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{c}{d} \cdot  \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-2}}{d} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{c}{d} \cdot  \frac{F_{n-2}}{d} \right\rfloor $$

##### Example for (1) where $c=3, d=2$

The simplest case with some interesting behaviour is $c = 3$ and $d = 2$. Despite different initial conditions $F_0$, quite a few of sequences become the same sequence when they share the same values:

> e.g.:
> $F_0 = 4, F_1 = 6, F_2 = 9,\color{red}{F_3 = 12, F_4 = 18,\dots}$
> $F_0 = 8 ,\color{red}{F_1 = 12, F_2 = 18,\dots}$

For clarity, I'll refer to the sequence $F_0, F_1, F_2, \dots$ as $\mathscr{F}(F_0)$
(e.g.: So $\mathscr{F}(4)$ is the sequence $4, 6, 9, \dots$)

Some observations that can be made are:

> Given sequence $(F_i)$ the following sequences share values:
>
> - $\mathscr{F}(F_i)$
> - $\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{2}{3}F_i\right)$ if $\frac{2}{3}F_i \in \mathbb{N}$
> - $\mathscr{F}(F_i + 1)$ if $F_i$ is even

It also seems every $\mathscr{F}(4 + 6n)$ is always a "new" sequence?

> It seems that if $\mathscr{F}(n)$ where $n < 4 + 6n$
> Then $\mathscr{F}(n)$ and $\mathscr{F}(4 + 6n)$ do not share any values.

Keeping track of every time an odd number appears in $\mathscr{F}(4)$ results in [A087791](https://oeis.org/A087791).

##### Special case for (2)

A special case for (2) can be solved using Theorem 3.10 from Concrete Mathematics:

> Let $f(x)$ be any continuous, monotonically increasing function with the property that:
> $$f(x) \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x \in \mathbb{Z}$$
> Then:
> $$\left\lfloor f(x) \right \rfloor = \left\lfloor f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \right\rfloor$$

Using $f(x) = abx + bc$, we can prove by induction that:
$$F_n = a\lfloor f^n(bF_0) \rfloor +c \text{ where } f^n(x) = f(\underbrace{f(f(\dots))}_\textrm{n times}$$
We can then prove $f^n(x_0) = (ab)^n x_0 + \frac{1-(ab)^n}{1-ab}cb$, and obtain the special case solution:

> If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$ satisfies $\left(abx + bc \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x \in \mathbb{Z}\right)$
> Then
> $$F_n = a \left\lfloor (ab)^{n-1} bF_0 + \frac{1-(ab)^{n-1}}{1-ab}cb \right\rfloor + c $$

Admittedly, I'm not quite happy with this result as the conditions are incredibly restrictive.

It also does not solve my original problem (even for cases $d|c$ or $c|d$?)

Are there general solutions to my problem?

Comment: Have you tried solving some simple small cases of your original problem?

Comment: Yes, when $c$ divides $d$ or $d$ divides $c$, the solution is relatively simple. I've also been assuming $F_0 \geq 0$. The problem isn't so trivial when $c,d$ are coprime. e.g. $c=3, d=2$, which degenerates for $F_0 < 4$, then $F_0 = 4$ and $F_0 = 5$ both converge to the same sequence. This happens quite often. However, you get new sequences every $F_0 = 4 + 6n$. I believe there is some elementary number theory/base conversion-like behaviour going on.

Comment: You should include what you have tried in your question, not wait to someone  ask you about it too post it in a comment.

Comment: Right, I'll add it to the question! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

For the original problem:

Set $G_n = \frac{F_n}{c}$. Then we have $G_n = \left\lfloor\frac{F_{n-1}}{d}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{c}{d}G_{n-1}\right\rfloor$

I think this form of the problem probably has been studied for some values of $\frac{c}{d}$ and some initial values. For example, for $c=3$ and $d=2$, with initial condition $G_1=2$ [can be found in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A061418), while the corresponding $F_n$ sequence cannot.

For that particular case it's known that $G_n = \left\lceil(\tfrac{3}{2})^{n-1}2\ \alpha\right\rceil$ where $\alpha$ is a constant related with the case $k=3$ of the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Sequences of the form $x_{n+1} = \lfloor \alpha\ x_n \rfloor$ for other values of $\alpha$ (not necessarily rational) can also be found on the OEIS, for example, $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ or $\alpha = \pi$

Comment: Neat! It looks like $F_n = c \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{F_{n-1}}{d} \right\rfloor$ can be solved generally, although with the caveat of having to compute $\alpha$ depending on $F_0, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$ (but maybe I'm being too optimistic)